# Group By Timestamp_Trunc including empty rows with '0' count

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery query as follows:

```
SELECT
  timestamp_trunc(timestamp,
    hour) hour,
  statusCode,
  CAST(AVG(durationMs) as integer) averageDurationMs,
  COUNT(*) count
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY
  hour,
  statusCode
```

And it works great, returning results like this:

[image]

However, my charting component needs empty rows for empty 'hours' (e.g. 18:00 should be 0, 19:00 = 0 etc)

Is there an elegant way to do this in BigQuery SQL or do I have to do it in code before returning to my UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try generating array of hours needed cross joining it with all the status codes and left joining with your results:

```
with mytable as (
    select timestamp '2021-10-18 19:00:00' as hour, 200 as statusCode, 1234 as averageDurationMs, 25 as count union all
    select '2021-10-18 21:00:00', 500, 4978, 6015 union all 
    select '2021-10-18 21:00:00', 404, 4987, 5984 union all 
    select '2021-10-18 21:00:00', 200, 5048, 11971 union all 
    select '2021-10-18 21:00:00', 401, 4976, 6030
)
select myhour, allCodes.statusCode, IFNULL(mytable.averageDurationMs, 0) as statusCode, IFNULL(mytable.count, 0) as averageDurationMs
from 
    UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), HOUR), INTERVAL 23 HOUR), TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), HOUR), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) as myhour
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT statusCode FROM mytable) as allCodes
LEFT JOIN mytable ON myHour = mytable.hour AND allCodes.statusCode = mytable.statusCode
```

[image]